# How to assign datareader value string array

Tags: c#, mysql, arrays

I am getting these records from database `MySql version 8.0.17`

```
+-------------------------+
| TABLE_NAME              |
+-------------------------+
| t_contents_s300_1_2021  |
| t_contents_s34d_1_2021  |
| t_contents_s34g_1_2021  |
| t_contents_s3sv_1_2021  |
+-------------------------+
```

and I used `MySqlDataReader` to read those records as follows

```
MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();    
// in reader, I have records which comes from database.

while(reader.Read())    
{
   string [] arpp_pro = new string[] {reader["TABLE_NAME"].ToString()};
}
```

everything works fine...

But I need assigning these values of `string [] arpp_pro` in array for execute single query INSERT INTO on new table for each values from `TABLE_NAME`

How to solve this problem.

How can I get all records in array from `TABLE_NAME`?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: I've removed references to ASP.NET as nothing in this question is unique to making web applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to construct a list:

```
MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();    

List<string> arpp_pro = new List<string>(); // define a list outside of the loop
while(reader.Read())    
{
   // for each row from the database, add the retrieved table name to the list
   arpp_pro.Add(reader["TABLE_NAME"].ToString()); 
}

// code to dos something with arpp_pro here.
```

I also recommend using the `using` keyword with your reader to ensure that it's closed/disposed when you are done with it. Example:

```
List<string> arpp_pro = new List<string>(); // define a list outside of the loop
using(MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while(reader.Read())    
    {
       // for each row from the database, add the retrieved table name to the list
       arpp_pro.Add(reader["TABLE_NAME"].ToString());
    }
}
```

If you really need it as an array, you can call `string[] arpp_pro_array = arpp_pro.ToArray();` to convert the list to an array. You will need `using System.Linq;` at the top of your code file for this to work, as `ToArray` is a LINQ extension method.

Comment: thanks for help, really appreciated. Plse see **update** in the question. I don't understand how to get the single value (table name) from the list

Comment: @Edward Why are you reading multiple values if you only need one? Only you know the logic of which table name you want, and what tells you that it's that one.

Comment: @John: a little note - since `reader` will return string values, cast will be faster than calling `ToString`, that is, `(string)reader["TABLE_NAME"]` instead of `reader["TABLE_NAME"].ToString()`.

Comment: @John pls see **logic** in the question. For each value from the list `arpp_pro` I need insert value on the table `t_contents_table_name_insert`

Comment: @Edward You specifically asked for _"How can I get all records in array from TABLE_NAME?"_, which I have answered. Your new edit is something else and should be its own question.

Comment: @Dennis That is actually not true. `(string)obj` does a cast, whereas the code for `string.ToString()` is `return this;`, so apart from an extra vtable lookup, it's going to take exactly the same time